# Understanding generics and how to avoid cast

Tags: java, generics, generic-collections

The following code is an example of what I hope to achieved. Unfortunately, there is no way to compile this code without a cast in the function `getElements()`.

I still have quite wrapped my head around Java generics completely, but this seems like a fairly simply case to get around.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
import org.junit.Test;

import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class GenericFruitTest
{
    @Test
    public void genericFruit()
    {
        Collection<Apple> apples = new FruitBasket().getApples();
        Collection<Orange> oranges = new FruitBasket().getOranges();

        Collection<Rye> rye = new BreadBasket().getRye();
    }

    class FruitBasket extends Basket<Fruit>
    {
        Collection<Apple> getApples()
        {
            return getElements(Apple.class);
        }

        Collection<Orange> getOranges()
        {
            return getElements(Orange.class);
        }
    }

    private class BreadBasket extends Basket<Bread>
    {
        private Collection<Rye> rye;

        public Collection<Rye> getRye()
        {
            return getElements(Rye.class);
        }
    }

    class Basket<E>
    {

        Map<Class<? extends E>, Collection<? extends E>> classCollectionMap = new HashMap<Class<? extends E>, Collection<? extends E>>();

        <T extends E> Collection<T> getElements(Class<T> elementClass)
        {
            // The following line throws compile time "incompatible types" without cast
            return classCollectionMap.get(elementClass);
        }

    }

    class Rye extends Bread
    {
    }

    class Apple extends Fruit
    {
    }

    class Orange extends Fruit
    {
    }

    class Fruit
    {
    }

    private class Bread
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: That's quite expected, since the compiler can't make any guarantee that a Collection<Orange> is indeed stored in the map, under the Orange.class key. It could be a Collection<Apple> or a Collection<Fruit>. With a Basket<Fruit> the only guarantee you can have is that the basket contains Fruits.

Comment: Is there a way using generics to guarantee what type of Fruit can be expected in the returned Collections?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It requires a casting because the compiler doesn't know the type of the collection that any given key has. Your map says that it maps *a `Class` of an unkwnown type to a `Collection` of an unknown type*, but you have no way of telling the map that they have to be the same type.

When working with generics, most of the time you *can't* get rid of the casts. Most of those casts are, however, *unchecked conversions* that are removed at runtime because of type erasure. The point is that, when **you** can guarantee type safety, the compiler leaves you alone and clients of your class get a type-safe, casting-free interface.

Of course, if you screw up, the runtime has no way of alerting you.

Answer (score 3):

The `Map` in this case is mapping from `Class<? extends E>` to `Collection<? extends E>`. Any  `Class<? extends E>` could legitimately as far as the compiler is concerned be put in mapping to any `Collection<? extends E>`.

The fact that you happen to have always put a class that matches the collection into the Map is not something the compiler is aware of - as you could put the class of anything that extends E into the map.

Unfortunately you are going to need the cast in this case - although at least generics lets you put the cast inside your method, so anyone using the method cannot see it.

Answer (score -2):

Just like Template meta Programing in C++, You must specify a specific type, otherwise compiler does not know how to run in runtime.